# How is the gzip file size encoded?

Tags: c++, c, encoding, gzip

The gzip file format contains the (uncompressed/original) file size encoded in the last 4 bytes of the compressed file.  The "gzip -l" command reports the compressed and uncompressed sizes, the compression ratio, the original filename.

Looking around stackoverflow, there are a couple of mentions of decoding the size encoded in the last 4 bytes.

What is the encoding of the size?  Big-endian (most significant byte first), Little-endian (least significant byte first), and is the value signed or unsigned?

This code snippet seems to be working for me,

```
FILE* fh; //assume file handle opened
unsigned char szbuf[4];
struct stat statbuf;
fstat(fn,&statbuf);
unsigned long clen=statbuf.st_size;
fseek(fh,clen-4,SEEK_SET);
int count=fread(szbuf,1,4,fh);
unsigned long ulen = ((((((szbuf[4-1] << 8) | szbuf[3-1]) << 8) | szbuf[2-1]) << 8) | szbuf[1-1]);
```

*Here are a couple of related posts, which seem to imply little-endian, and unsigned long (0..4GB-1).*

[Determine uncompressed size of GZIP file](http://www.abeel.be/comment/reply/99#comment-form)

[GZIPOutputStream not updating Gzip size bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25436895/gzipoutputstream-not-updating-gzip-size-bytes)

[Determine size of file in gzip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947286/how-do-i-tell-in-perl-what-the-size-of-a-file-inside-a-gzip-archive-is-without-u)

[Gzip.org has more information about Gzip](http://www.gzip.org/)

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727599/1180620) for why that length should in general not be relied upon.

Comment: Agreed. For single files encoded once, of a certain size (under 2^32 bytes), the RFC gives you the way to pull the last 4-bytes to get the file size.  Perhaps not completely general, but still very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RFC says it's modulo 2^32 which means `uint32_t`, and experimentation using a .Net `GZipStream` gives it as little-endian.

[RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952#section-2.2)

Comment: I added the RFC link.

Comment: Your experimental results are confirmed in section 2.1 of RFC 1952:  "All multi-byte numbers in the format described here are stored with the least-significant byte first (at the lower memory address)."

Comment: As you have pointed out, the RFC (section 2.1) specifies byte order as least significant byte to most significant byte.  Thus the ISIZE 4-byte file size is stored little-endian (as experimental results have confirmed).